# Rails3 ajax upload with Iframe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-3, unobtrusive-javascript, multifile-uploader

before rails3 I had a working multiple ajax(mootools) file upload solution.
I used form_to_remote with an iframe and responds_to_parent.

In rails3 the ajax upload with form_tag remote => true, traget => "my_iframe" doesn't work.
The the param[:uploaded_image]with the file is missing.
I don't know why.

Can anyone recommend a good ajax file upload solution?

Answer (score 3):

The remotipart gem might be what you want, it's muchi simpler to use than responds_to_parent and it's working with rails 3. Please refer to:

https://github.com/formasfunction/remotipart